Why wont the drag and drop handling work?
I drag off elements and when they overlap they don't send the server message (checked through networking).
There is no glitches in the UI.
I don't have much details about the problem that's all i know.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Element Combiner</title>
    <style>
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="sidebar">
        <div class="draggable" id="fire" draggable="true"> Fire</div>
        <div class="draggable" id="earth" draggable="true"> Earth</div>
        <div class="draggable" id="water" draggable="true"> Water</div>
        <div class="draggable" id="wind" draggable="true">️ Wind</div>
    </div>
    <div id="drop-area"></div>

    <script>
let draggedElement = null;
    let offsetX = 0, offsetY = 0;

    document.querySelectorAll('.draggable').forEach(item => {
        item.addEventListener('dragstart', (e) => {
            e.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', e.target.id);
            draggedElement = e.target.cloneNode(true);
            draggedElement.style.position = 'absolute';
            draggedElement.style.zIndex = 100;

            const rect = e.target.getBoundingClientRect();
            offsetX = e.clientX - rect.left;
            offsetY = e.clientY - rect.top;

            document.body.appendChild(draggedElement);

            draggedElement.style.left = `${e.clientX - offsetX}px`;
            draggedElement.style.top = `${e.clientY - offsetY}px`;

            document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
            document.addEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp);
        });
    });

    function onMouseMove(event) {
        if (draggedElement) {
            draggedElement.style.left = `${event.clientX - offsetX}px`;
            draggedElement.style.top = `${event.clientY - offsetY}px`;
        }
    }

    function onMouseUp(event) {
        if (draggedElement) {
            document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
            document.removeEventListener('mouseup', onMouseUp);
            
            const dropArea = document.getElementById('drop-area');
            const dropRect = dropArea.getBoundingClientRect();
            const elRect = draggedElement.getBoundingClientRect();

            if (elRect.left < dropRect.right &&
                elRect.right > dropRect.left &&
                elRect.top < dropRect.bottom &&
                elRect.bottom > dropRect.top) {

                const dropTarget = draggedElement.cloneNode(true);
                dropTarget.classList.remove('draggable');
                dropTarget.classList.add('drop-target');
                dropTarget.style.position = 'absolute';
                dropTarget.style.left = `${event.clientX - dropArea.getBoundingClientRect().left - offsetX}px`;
                dropTarget.style.top = `${event.clientY - dropArea.getBoundingClientRect().top - offsetY}px`;

                dropArea.appendChild(dropTarget);
                makeDraggable(dropTarget);
            }

            document.body.removeChild(draggedElement);
            draggedElement = null;
        }
    }

    function makeDraggable(element) {
        element.addEventListener('mousedown', (e) => {
            const rect = element.getBoundingClientRect();
            const offsetX = e.clientX - rect.left;
            const offsetY = e.clientY - rect.top;

            function moveAt(x, y) {
                element.style.left = `${x - offsetX}px`;
                element.style.top = `${y - offsetY}px`;
            }

            function onMouseMove(event) {
                moveAt(event.clientX, event.clientY);
            }

            document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
            document.addEventListener('mouseup', () => {
                document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
            }, { once: true });
        });
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>

I tried methods to see what part wasn't working the server was fine its just the element combining functionality wont work.

Did you ensure that onMouseUp accurately calculates whether the dragged element is within the bounds of the drop area.

Is there a reason that you don't use the events dragover and drop on the target/drop area?

Another question: You write "don't send the server message" -- what message? There is no indication of anything being send in the code.

A lot of stuff to cover. Here are some points:

Try not to use that many IDs. They have to be unique, and when you start cloning elements this can end up in a mess. Use the data-* attribute instead.
You can use event delegation instead of assigning event listeners to each draggable item, like sidebar.addEventListener('dragstart', e => {});.
The e.target is not always the element you expect. In the drop zone, it you drop on another item, that item is the e.target -- not the #drop-area. So, use e.target.closest('#drop-area') to find the element.
Use the e.dataTransfer for data about the item being dragged, including the position of the mouse in relation to the item being dragged.

In the example you can start dragging from both sidebar and drop-area, therefor two event listeners for dragstart. Notice that there is a difference between the data send in each case. And in the drop callback I then do two different things depending on the "type" (id or name).


const sidebar = document.getElementById('sidebar');
const drop_area = document.getElementById('drop-area');

sidebar.addEventListener('dragstart', e => {
  let sidebar = e.target.closest('#sidebar');
  let item = e.target.closest('.draggable');
  let data = {
    x: e.clientX - item.offsetLeft - sidebar.offsetLeft,
    y: e.clientY - item.offsetTop - sidebar.offsetTop,
    name: item.dataset.name
  };
  e.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', JSON.stringify(data));
});

drop_area.addEventListener('dragstart', e => {
  let drop_area = e.target.closest('#drop-area');
  let item = e.target.closest('.draggable');
  let data = {
    x: e.clientX - item.offsetLeft - drop_area.offsetLeft,
    y: e.clientY - item.offsetTop - drop_area.offsetTop,
    id: item.dataset.id
  };
  e.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', JSON.stringify(data));
});

drop_area.addEventListener('dragover', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let drop_area = e.target.closest('#drop-area');
  drop_area.classList.add('dragover');
});

drop_area.addEventListener('drop', e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  let drop_area = e.target.closest('#drop-area');
  drop_area.classList.remove('dragover');
  let data = JSON.parse(e.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain'));
  if(data.name){
    let item = sidebar.querySelector(`div[data-name="${data.name}"]`); 
    let clone = item.cloneNode(true);
    clone.style.left = (e.clientX - drop_area.offsetLeft - data.x) + 'px';
    clone.style.top = (e.clientY - drop_area.offsetTop - data.y) + 'px';
    drop_area.append(clone);
  }else if(data.id){
    let item = drop_area.querySelector(`div[data-id="${data.id}"]`);
    item.style.left = (e.clientX - drop_area.offsetLeft - data.x) + 'px';
    item.style.top = (e.clientY - drop_area.offsetTop - data.y) + 'px';
  }
  drop_area.querySelectorAll('.draggable').forEach((item, i) => item.dataset.id = i);
});
body {
  display: flex;
  gap: 2em;
}

#sidebar {
  position: relative;
}

.draggable {
  cursor: grab;
}

#drop-area {
  border: solid black thin;
  width: 400px;
  min-height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

#drop-area.dragover {
  background-color: #eee;
}

#drop-area .draggable {
  position: absolute;
  display: inline;
  cursor: grab;
}
<div id="sidebar">
  <div class="draggable" data-name="fire" draggable="true"> Fire</div>
  <div class="draggable" data-name="earth" draggable="true"> Earth</div>
  <div class="draggable" data-name="water" draggable="true"> Water</div>
  <div class="draggable" data-name="wind" draggable="true">️ Wind</div>
</div>
<div id="drop-area"></div>



